# Collapse taxonomy fieldset on node form by default

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view, cck

While creating a (custom) content in Drupal, I have three vocabularies. But these make my create content page very heavy. I want to collapse the Vocubalary fieldset by default and want it to expand only if user chooses to.

Comment: I edited your question and title to clarify what you want, as I assume by 'DropDown', you mean the fieldset (the collapsible/expandable frame around the taxonomy fields). If this is not what you meant, just revert my change (or tell me to do so).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you mean that the taxonomy fieldset should be displayed as collapsed by default, you can achieve that by implementing `hook_form_alter()`:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_form_alter().
 */
function yourModule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // TODO: Adjust the form id according to your content type
  if ($form_id == 'yourContentType_node_form') {
    // Collapse 'Vocabularies' fieldset.
    $form['taxonomy']['#collapsed'] = TRUE;
  }
}
```

Comment: Having trouble getting your example to work.  Can you say more about what yourContentType_node_form should look like?

Answer (score 1):

[Big Autocomplete TAXonomy (BATAX)](http://drupal.org/project/batax) will probably do what you want.

Comment: Not actually, for two fields I am already using Autocomplete fields. I just want the drop down Vocubulary which is opened by default should be closed by default.